# Is it okay to pass next function as a parameter in express?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm passing the `NextFunction` from express to another function but my test to test `if user with given email doesn't exist` isn't passing. Is the `next` function not working as it should when passed as a parameter to another function here?

```
const lookupUserByEmail = async (
  email: string,
  next: NextFunction
): Promise<UserType | any> => {
  let user: UserType | null;
  try {
    user = await User.findOne({ where: { email } });
    if (!user) {
      return next(
        createError(401, {
          message: 'Invalid email credentials.',
        })
      );
    }
  } catch (err) {
    return next(createError(500, 'Internal server error'));
  }
  return user;
};

export const signin = async (
  req: Request<{}, {}, SigninUserInput['body']>,
  res: Response,
  next: NextFunction
) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  // check if an user with given email exists
  const user: UserType = await lookupUserByEmail(email, next.bind(signin));

  // check password
  if (isPasswordWrong(password, user.password)) {
    return next(createError(401, { message: 'Invalid credentials.' }));
  }

  const token = createToken(
    {
      id: user.id,
      username: user.username,
      email: user.email,
    },
    next
  );

  res
    .status(200)
    .json({ token: token, id: user.id, preference: user.preference });
};
```

Comment: You certainly _shouldn't_ pass `next` around, that way the whole rest of your codebase gets coupled to the transport layer (see also: throwing errors with status codes in). `lookupUserByEmail` is a persistence layer function, it should contain nothing related to the transport layer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How should I handle `lookupUserByEmail`?